# Boolean modifier does not cut correctly out of mesh

Tags: modifiers

I have a series of arches that I want to cut out of a wall. I applied a boolean modifier to the walls and then selected the arches and instead of cutting the arches out, it cuts out random shapes.

I have removed all duplicate vertices and checked all normals are facing the right way. Does anyone have an idea what's causing this?

This is it with the arches displayed...

[image]

And this is with the arches hidden so boolean modifier shown...

[image]

Comment: Try the fast solver option.  Exact solver is good for some situations, but appears to completely muck up things that the old algorithm had no problem with.

Comment: Or is it possible that normals are flipped on one of the arches?

Comment: if you still have the problem, please provide blend file

Comment: This question was closed due to lack of details or clarity. You can edit your question and it will be automatically queued for review to be reopened.